# Create Hibernate For Joining Table

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have to join 2 tables. The column is want to join is email from candidate table and password from user table. How to do it. Can Someone Help me. candidate 
table is Shown Below:

```
CREATE TABLE `candidate` (`candidate_id` bigint(12) NOT NULL,`user_id`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`firstname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`lastname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`dob` date DEFAULT NULL,`gender` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `profile_title` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `profile_summary` varchar(10000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `total_experience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'year,month', `current_location` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `current_salary` double DEFAULT NULL, `expected_salary` double DEFAULT NULL, `status` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `percentage` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,`updated_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `noticeperiod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `martialstatus` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `currentoffer` double DEFAULT NULL, `idproof` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `industry` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`functionalarea` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `functionalrole` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `resign` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`preferlocation` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`notice_period_update` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL `passport` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`gross_salary` double DEFAULT NULL,`profile_type` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`rrm_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`candidate_id`), KEY `Candidate_Address_idx` (`address_id`),KEY `Can_user` (`user_id`),KEY `CandidateStatus_idx` (`status`),KEY `CandidatePercent_idx` (`percentage`),KEY `user_id_idx` (`rrm_user_id`),CONSTRAINT `Can_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,CONSTRAINT `Candidate_Address`FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`rrm_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

User is:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`password` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, `last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`active` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`timezone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`created_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,`updated_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`activationcode` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`secure_key` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1505 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Why don't you just try reading some documentation? You'll get the answer to this question only to find that you don't know how to do the next thing. It is much slower for you to program without doing some research!

Comment: I tried reading many of the articles and tutorial but I couldnt find my way. Thats why I Raised this here.

Comment: Can I get Any Help??

Answer (score 0):

You need a very simple SQL query to do this:

```
SELECT
  c.candidate_id,
  c.user_id,
  c.email,
  u.password
FROM
  candidate as c
JOIN user as u ON c.user_id = u.user_id
```

Working example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ba876/1

Try to learn some SQL before you try to progress in this field.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/